# apache setup multiple doc root

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have apache2 server with a private IP.
Also, I have multiple applications that need to run on the same server.

Is there any solution to setup different document root for each application

Like ..

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/application to doc root /var/ww/html
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/application1  to doc root /var/www/html/app1/public
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/application2  to doc root /var/ww/html/app2/public
```

Comment: This is usually done using different "hosts" on a single http server. By that you get different names like `https://app1.example.com` and a separation of configuration and files for your application. Just take a look at the documentation, it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.